# How can I specify a version of a topic, example or part thereof?

Tags: support, documentation, language-versions

I would like to add a topic that only applies to a specific version of a language (tag). How do I specify that?

Likewise, how do I add an example to a topic and define what versions it is available in? How do I add an alternative version of an example for a newer language or vice versa: how do I add example content to substitute what is only available in newer versions?

What markdown is used to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For a topic

You can select the versions it applies to: when editing a topic, there’s a *Versions* field under the *Title* field. However, if you want to specify that the topic applies to all versions, you should *deselect* them all. That way, if a new version comes along, the topic doesn't hint that it no longer applies to that version.

The available versions are defined in the *Overview Topic* (there is a *Versions* block that contains a block).

#### For an example

This can be done with comment syntax. The versions have to be defined for the topic first.

The basic cases:

```
<!-- if version [eq 42] -->
    version = 42
<!-- end version if -->

<!-- if version [neq 42] -->
    version != 42
<!-- end version if -->

<!-- if version [lte 42] -->
    version <= 42
<!-- end version if -->

<!-- if version [lt 42] -->
    version < 42
<!-- end version if -->

<!-- if version [gte 42] -->
    version >= 42
<!-- end version if -->

<!-- if version [gt 42] -->
    version > 42
<!-- end version if -->
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#inline-versions for more (version groups; multiple conditionals).