# What is the best way to address changing documentation due to different version of a software?

Tags: discussion, documentation

I have the case of a library which have 4 versions, the last of which having gone through a rewrite (say only 60% of the API is similar, and the innerworkings have completely changed).

My question is :

- is it better to request a documentation tag per version?
- is there a way to address versioning when posting an example or else on the documentation site? Like when you post anything, you can put the version which applies. Or you can make a search on docs for a given version.

Comment: <!-- if version [gt x.y] --> new awesomeness <!-- end version if --> <!-- if version [lt x.y] --> not so awesome anymore <!-- end version if -->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't request a documentation tag per version.

Frameworks like .NET, platforms like iOS, and languages like Python or Swift all have multiple versions, yet they are each documented under a single tag.

You should [use the version feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329084/how-can-i-specify-a-version-of-a-topic-example-or-part-thereof) to specify the version which is documented.

Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/188/objects/1303/shallow-clones) from the documentation.