# Symfony documentation: what to do?

Tags: discussion, documentation

After [this change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297725/alias-tag-synonyms-symfony2-and-symfony3-symfony?noredirect=1&lq=1) we solved the problem for questions, but the documentation has still tags for `symfony`, `symfony2` and `symfony3`.

It makes no sense to have 3 separate tags, but I don't know which tag(s) should be removed. What's the best way to have this problem solved?

Comment: [What is the best way to address changing documentation due to different version of a software?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329158/what-is-the-best-way-to-address-changing-documentation-due-to-different-version?rq=1)

Comment: @Veve That's not the question. There are 13 versions of Symfony (2.0-2.8, 3.0-3.3, ignoring 1.x) and we've got 3 tags. As said in the other discussion, 2.8 and 3.0 are almost identical so it makes no sense to have a separate tag  for Symfony 3. We solved this issue for Questions, now we should do it for Documentation.